# Sound Pool and Hash Map

Tags: android, soundpool

I have approximately 100 audio files in the raw folder this 100 files are just says numbers from 1 to 100.

After I click on a button. I want it to play the number according to the text entered in the text box.

So I use sound pool and hash map for it. This works just fine without any issues

```
soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
soundsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
soundsMap.put(1, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.number1, 1));
soundsMap.put(2, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.number2, 1));
```

like the above till number100.  I fetch the value of the text field

I put a for loop from 1 to 100. what ever the value will be played.

using the soundPool.play(1,....)

This works just fine without any issue.

But strange thing in this is that since it is creating haspmap of 100 value.. there is 5 seconds delay and with blank screen and I can't do anything with process is going on.

Is there any way to just create hashmap according to the value and plays the sound.

Like say for e.g

If text field has value 20

```
in the for loop: i=1 to 100..
it should get the value 20:
string a = "R.raw.number"+i
SoundsMap.put(1, soundPool.load(this, a, 1));
soundPool.play(1,....)
```

if the above is possible... How do I do it?

Awaiting your response!
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this is strange. You're loading 100 audio files. That takes time. You could do this in a background thread (perhaps using `AsyncTask`) and display a progress bar while loading. I'm not clear what you're using your for loop for though.

Comment: Oh god, are you looping 100 times testing `if(editText.getText().equals(String.valueOf(i)))`? Nonononno. Parse the input into a number and go from there. Check my example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why initialize everything at the start? What if the user never clicks more than a few buttons? I'd suggest loading on your button click, something like this:

```
//in onCreate()

final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_input_field);
int[] sounds = { R.raw.number1, R.raw.number2,
                 R.raw.number3, /*etc.*/ };

//in your onClick()

try {
    Double value = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText());
    int soundId = soundPool.load(MyActivity.this, sounds[value - 1], 1);
    soundPool.play(soundId, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    //Alert the user that an invalid number was entered
}
```

Comment: Thanks... This code worked except that I had to put the onLoadListener with if condition. Thanks for your help! :)